# Using `foobar or die` on return statment - unexpected result

Tags: php

Can please somebody explain unexpected result when using code like this:

```
return getObj() or die('Bye');
```

When `getObj` returns object, the `true` (`bool`) will be returned instead of the object.

But if I do this:

```
$obj = getObj() or die('Bye');
return $obj;
```

The object will be returned.

Full example:

```
<?php

echo "before testWrong\n";
$ret = testWrong();
var_dump($ret); // obj expected, bool returned
echo "after testWrong\n";

echo "\n";

echo "before testCorrect\n";
$ret = testCorrect();
var_dump($ret);  // obj expected, obj returned
echo "after testCorrect\n";

function testWrong()
{
    return createObj() or die('bye');
}

function testCorrect()
{
    $obj = createObj() or die('bye');

    return $obj;
}

function createObj()
{
    //return false;
    return new stdClass();
}
```

Output:

```
before testWrong
bool(true)
after testWrong

before testCorrect
object(stdClass)#1 (0) {
}
after testCorrect
```

I couldn't find anything on [php.net](https://www.php.net/), except one comment warning about this behavior, but without any explanation.

Also I am aware that this way of error handling is not nice - but this is not the point of the question.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`or` has lower precedence than `=`, so

```
$obj = getObj() or die();
```

is parsed as if it were

```
($obj = getObj()) or die();
```

So this assigns the object to `$obj()`, then tests the result of this.

But `return` is a statement, not an operator. It evaluates its entire argument, so it's equivalent to:

```
$temp = (getObj() or die());
return $temp;
```

The `or` operator always returns a boolean value, so the truthy result of `getObj()` gets converted to `TRUE`.

Comment: Excellent answer. I really didn't think about operator precedence in the context of this problem! Thx!